# Gatsby's mapping between markdown files

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I'm creating a multi-author site (using `gatsby-plugin-mdx`) and have the following file structure:

```
/posts
- /post-1/index.mdx
- /post-2/index.mdx
- ...
/members
- /member-a/index.mdx
- /member-b/index.mdx
- ...
```

In the frontmatter of the `post` page I have an array of authors like

```
authors: [Member A, Member B]
```

and I have the name of the author in the frontmatter of the author's markdown file.

I'd like to set the schema up so that when I query the post, I also get the details of the authors as well (name, email, etc.).

From reading [this page](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/#createresolvers-api) it seems like I need to create a custom resolver... but all the examples I see have all the authors in one `json` file (so you have two collections, `MarkdownRemark` and `AuthorJson`... while I think for my case all my posts and members are in `MarkdownRemark` collection.

Thanks so much!

Comment: This is the section of the doc that's about mapping foreign-key fields: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/#foreign-key-fields

Comment: @LekoArts Thanks. Don't think I understand the document enough to get it to work for me :P (get sth like `GraphQLError: Field "authors" of type "[Mdx]" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "authors { ... }"?`) I ended up doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65989605/3230090) which isn't ideal but it works. Would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up doing something like this. Surely there's a cleaner way, but it works for me. It goes through all the `Mdx` and add a field called `authors`, which is queried, to all `Mdx` types.

One problem with this is that there's also `authors` under `members`, which is not ideal. A better approach is to define new types and change `Mdx` in the last resolver to your new post data type. Not sure how to get that to work though. At the end, I could query something like:

```
query MyQuery {
  posts {
    frontmatter {
      title
      subtitle
    }
    authors {
      frontmatter {
        name
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
  const resolvers = {
    Mdx: {
      authors: {
        type: ["Mdx"],
        resolve(source, args, context, info) {
          return context.nodeModel.runQuery({
            query: {
              filter: {
                fields: {
                  collection: { eq: "members" }
                },
                frontmatter: {
                  memberid: { in: source.frontmatter.authors },
                },
              },
            },
            type: "Mdx",
            firstOnly: false,
          })
        }
      }
    },
  }
  createResolvers(resolvers)
}
```